# Yet another Alice and Bob dice question

Tags: probability, dice

I'm not sure how to solve this puzzle:

> Alice and Bob play a simple dice game. They take turns rolling a single die, starting with Alice, until one of them wins by getting a 6. In the end it turns out that Bob won. What is the probability that he won on his first roll?

Let $B_i$ be the outcome of Bob's die on round $i$. Clearly, $\mathbb{P}(B_i = k) = 1/6$ for any value $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. However, the question is effectively asking

$$
\mathbb{P}(B_1 = 6 \mid \text{Bob wins}) = \;?
$$

Is the answer just $1/6$ since $B_1$ is independent of whether or not Bob wins? This seems counterintuitive to me, because it seems like conditioning on the event that Bob wins should change things. I am uncertain.

Comment: What's the probability $B$ wins?  What's the probability $B$ wins in the first round?

Comment: "*Since $B_1$ is independent of whether or not Bob wins?*"  You should be able to see clearly that this is not independent.  To see this, consider $\Pr(\text{Bob win}\mid B_1=6)=\frac{5}{6}$ and comparing to $\Pr(\text{Bob win})<0.5$ (*seen by very loose observation that Alice should be more likely to win since rules are same for each but alice gets to go first.  Exact value is able to be calculated*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

You have to compute it.

$$P(B_1=6|\text{Bob wins}) = \frac{P(A_1 \ne 6, B_1 = 6)}{P(\text{Bob wins})}$$

$$P(\text{Bob wins}) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty P(\text{Bob wins at } j^{th} \text{ round})$$

Try to write down the $P(\text{Bob wins at } j \text{ round})$ and then use geometric series to compute the quantity.